# User registration process in django？

Tags: python, django, authentication, registration

I want user to regist my app in two step

1. basic info (email username password)
2. realinfo   (realname, age, gender )

and this is how I did

```
def developRegistrationFirstStep(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['username'], form.cleaned_data['email'], form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            # user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            # if user is not None:
            #    if user.is_active:
            #       login(request, user)
            return redirect('registration/secondstep')
   else:
       form = RegistrationForm()
   return render_to_response('registration/registration_form.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def developRegistrationSecondStep(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileInfo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
```

note that both registration step has to be finished before the user can login

as u can see after user done with first step,I redirect the user to the second step,and here is the problem, in second step how can I get this half registed user? because I stroe the realinfo in UserProfile model,which gets created once the user instance gets created,
I need to save the realinfo into this user's UserProfile, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly where the Django [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) is a helpful tool

Comment: oh my!!! can't belive there is built in app for this. django is awesome， thank you so much.